# Change date format in antd <DatePicker /> VueJs

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, antd

I'm submitting a form to send data to my API that receives date in the format of YYYY-MM-DD but by default the DatePicker component keeps adding extra characters of time to the end of the date, for example when I enter a date for my date of birth field the value is stored in the format below
`{ "date":"2003-02-03T13:32:49.543Z" }`
I would prefer it to be just
`{ "date":"03-02-2003" }`

below is the code for the form and its submit function

```
<template>
    <a-form :model="state" name="basic" autocomplete="off">
         <a-form-item label="Ten cong viec" name="nameJob">
                 <a-input v-model:value="state.nameJob" />
         </a-form-item>
         <a-form-item label="Date" name="date">
                 <a-date-picker v-model:value="state.date" :format="dateFormatList" />
         </a-form-item>
         <a-form-item>
                 <a-button type="primary" html-type="submit" style="margin-left: 10px" @click="handleCreateJob">Submit</a-button>
    </a-form>
</template>
<script setup>
import {reactive} from 'vue';
const dateFormatList = ['DD/MM/YYYY'];
const state = reactive({
    nameJob: '',
    date: ""
});

const handleCreateJob = async () => {

    try {
        await createJob({ nameJob: state.nameJob, date: state.date })
    } catch (e) {
        }
};
</script >
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `valueFormat` with the custom format value you want to store:

```js
<a-date-picker v-model:value="state.date" :format="dateFormatList" valueFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" />
```